How to generate SOAPRequest using Input C# Object and Deserialize SOAP response into C# OutputResponse Object
I am trying to achieve these 2 things:

Generate SoapRequest from this Input C# object
Deserialize Big SoapResponse into C# object

I have tested the Input SOAPRequest in Postman. I have directly passed CustomerID, CustomerName And CustomerNumber as pasrt of the Input SOAPRequest.
But in realtime, I have to dynamically generate this SOAPRequest using the C#Object and Deserialize that received SOAPResponse into C#Object.
Input Customer Object:
public class CustomerRequest
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNum { get; set; }     

}

Input SOAPRequest:
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>1</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Get_Customers_Request bsvc:version="v42.0">
         <bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Customer_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="?">
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Customer_ID">100001</bsvc:ID>
               <bsvc:Customer_Name>ShellGroup</bsvc:Customer_Name>
               <bsvc:Customer_Num>S0001</bsvc:Customer_Num>
            </bsvc:Customer_Reference>
         </bsvc:Request_References>
         <bsvc:Response_Group>
            <bsvc:Include_Reference>1</bsvc:Include_Reference>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>1</bsvc:Include_Customer_Data>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>1</bsvc:Include_Customer_Balance>
            <bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>1</bsvc:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>
         </bsvc:Response_Group>
      </bsvc:Get_Customers_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Output C# object:
public class CustomerResponse
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string WID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCategory { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public decimal YTDSalesAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalBalance { get; set; }

}

Output SOAPResponse:
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Customers_Response wd:version="v42.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <wd:Request_References>
            <wd:Customer_Reference wd:Descriptor="DRS Test Customer">
               <wd:ID wd:type="WID">c367dfff098d100072372cd7d2b10000</wd:ID>
               <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Reference_ID">DRS_Test_Customer</wd:ID>
               <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_ID">100001</wd:ID>
            </wd:Customer_Reference>
         </wd:Request_References>
         <wd:Response_Group>
            <wd:Include_Reference>0</wd:Include_Reference>
            <wd:Include_Customer_Data>0</wd:Include_Customer_Data>
            <wd:Include_Customer_Balance>1</wd:Include_Customer_Balance>
            <wd:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>0</wd:Include_Customer_Activity_Detail>
         </wd:Response_Group>
         <wd:Response_Results>
            <wd:Total_Results>1</wd:Total_Results>
            <wd:Total_Pages>1</wd:Total_Pages>
            <wd:Page_Results>1</wd:Page_Results>
            <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
         </wd:Response_Results>
         <wd:Response_Data>
            <wd:Customer>
               <wd:Customer_Balance_Data>
                  <wd:Default_Currency_Reference wd:Descriptor="USD">
                     <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9e996ffdd3e14da0ba7275d5400bafd4</wd:ID>
                     <wd:ID wd:type="Currency_ID">USD</wd:ID>
                     <wd:ID wd:type="Currency_Numeric_Code">840</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Default_Currency_Reference>
                  <wd:YTD_Sales_Amount>235649.87</wd:YTD_Sales_Amount>
                  <wd:Total_Balance>-107961.63</wd:Total_Balance>
                  <wd:Last_12_Months_Sales_Amount>235649.87</wd:Last_12_Months_Sales_Amount>
                  <wd:Overdue_Balance>-107961.63</wd:Overdue_Balance>
               </wd:Customer_Balance_Data>
            </wd:Customer>
         </wd:Response_Data>
      </wd:Get_Customers_Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>


SOAP services are created and called using WCF, not Web API. A SOAP services is described by its WSDL document which specifies all operations and their DTOs, not just a single operation

@PanagiotisKanavos not true, you can invoke SOAP services from HttpClient in .NET Core+.

@D3vtr0n True, but generally you would use the WSDL, which gives you the full specification for all calls, and auto-generate the (de-)serialization code from that, rather than trying to code it yourself.

@D3vtr0n not not true. Sure, you can assemble a skyscraper one brick at a time. That doesn't mean it's smart. Especially when you don't know what the protocols are, or what additional standards you must adhere to, like authentication. Workday expects all calls to follow its specifications and will reject any call that doesn't. If the OP wants to create a testing proxy, they must follow that spec

@PanagiotisKanavos you do if its internal SOAP calls, like in my team's situation

Let me guess - you're trying to call a service, perhaps an airline, banking or Oracle service that breaks the SOAP standard, so you had to revert to raw calls. That doesn't mean this is normal or safe. Perhaps the service provider even says the WSDL is for reference purposes only, and they're free to violate them at will?

This is Workday API's. We don't have WSDL's and not WCF service. So, we have to dynamically build this SOAPRequest and send it to HttpWebRequest. I have tested by passing this Input SOAPRequest the hardcoding. I got response back.

AFAIK Workday's SOAP web service does expose WSDLs. You can retrieve these by visiting the service endpoint with a "?wsdl" suffix. However, you don't need the WSDL file to set up the automatic gen. From Visual Studio go to Add Service Reference then select the "Advanced" and down at the bottom under "Compatibility" is "Add Web Reference". Enter the service endpoint and it will add a proxy all wired up for SOAP. They also have a standard REST API as well.

This link was the first place I got to via Google and has links for WSDL for each API https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/index.html

@StevePy However, you don't need the WSDL file to set up the automatic gen - er, well you kinda do, it's just that you don't see VS retrieve it and make the stubs from it but I'm in agreement with your approach

Yeah, just meant you don't need to have sourced a copy, VS extracts it from the SOAP service on the premise it is a properly set up SOAP service, which I expect that Workday's is. Basically guard against the argument "There isn't a WSDL because they didn't give us a WSDL".

You Just need to attach the soap service as a connected service in VS.
Right Click in your project ==> Add Service Reference ==> Select "WCF Web Service" and follow the form inserting WSDL url or the WSDL xml file.
After that all the classes and methods you need  (including response class models) will be generated by VS.
You can also use HttpClient passing the xml request in body, but it will require more effort generating class models.
If you still prefer this way, vs past special can help you generating the class, for example you can do the calls using postaman, and then copying the xml result pasting with "paste special" in a new class file.
